# AspNetCore WebApp not passing users windows credentials to API

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, blazor-webassembly, windows-authentication

I'm building a simple AspNetCore Balzor server app that calls an endpoint of an AspNetCore web Api.  Both are hosted in IIS on a windows server.

When I run the website via IIS Express locally (pointing at the api on our windows server) everything thing works as expected.  If I launch the hosted website, I get "HHTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized".

This leads me to believe it is a double hop issue, but I really don't know how to resolve it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is the set up

- Both have IIS Authentication set to "Windows Authentication" on the server.
- Both have "builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenicationScheme) in Program.cs.

These are the basic tests I've done

- Call the end point directly from a browser
- Added my windows user name & password directly into the CredentialCache, it returns the data.

  var cache = new CredentialCache();
  cache.Add(url, "Negotiate", new NetworkCredential("username", "password"));
  var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = cache, PreAuthenticate = true };
  var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler) { Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10) };
  var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

UPDATE: This is from the HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
Detailed Error Information

Module: UrlAuthorizationModule

Notification: AuthorizedRequest

Handler: aspNetCore

Error Code: 0x80070005

Request URL:http://*servername*.com:*port*/*endpoint*

Logon Method: Negotiate

Logon User: *domain**servername*$

Comment: Don’t use Windows authentication then. There are so many modern alternatives.

Comment: I believe that's for domain authorization and the browser will probably need to know that the URL is local... i.e. "trusted zone" to run negotiate.  You mention "hosted website" here, which means that server is probably not a part of the domain.

Comment: What I mean by "hosted" is the api is on IIS which is running on our windows server.  The website is also there., but I'll certainly investigate the "trusted zone" stuff.  Thanks

Comment: You mentioned that it's a blazor server app to call external web api, so that we should follow the section [Server-side scenarios for calling external web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0#server-side-scenarios-for-calling-external-web-apis) could you pls help confirm whether you used similar method and added the credential into your http request?

Comment: The "external" api is running on the same windows server as the website.  It works when I set the api's authorization rules to allow "all users" or "all anonymous users".  The HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized suggests that the logon user is not my windows is, but the server "name".

Comment: You might check here to see if the FQDN is causing it to be read as internet instead of intranet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/intranet-site-identified-as-an-internet-site

Comment: symptom of the above quirk would be if you are always prompted to enter your password instead of it passing through automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I created a web api and choosing windows auth as the Authentication Type using the template in vs2022. And created another blazor server app in .net 7 which choosing Windows Auth as well when creating.

I had code below in the blazor server app to call the API which worked well both in local side and publishing to IIS. Only difference is that in IIS I need to enable windows authentication and disable allow anonymous.

```
@inject IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory

<div>@res</div>

@code {
    private string res;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now));
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
            // "https://localhost:7244/WeatherForecast");
        "http://localhost:8098/WeatherForecast");

        // var client = ClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }   
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I've mimic what you did, and I agree this works.  However, when I implement tighter authorization, it no longer works.  The default IIS Authorization Rules are Allow "All Users".  When I remove this and just enter my windows Id the IIS website no longer returns the api json.  But, when I start the website with IIS Express in my machine it does.  My guess is the second hop is losing my credentials and connecting as "anonymous".

Comment: sorry I can't reproduce your issue in my side...

Comment: if the server is making the call, it'll be running as whatever user the apppool is running as.  (running as default app pool?)  You'd need to allow that user domain access.  (Otherwise you'd have to "impersonate?": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/xh507fc5(v=vs.100) )